# Make things glow in the game engine

Tags: game-engine, light

I recently learned how to make things glow in regular blender. It's a pretty cool effect that would go nicely in a game, but when I switch from cycles render to blender game, it no longer has the same emit effect as before. Is there a way to make it keep the effect in the game engine? Thanks.

Comment: Cycles is a completely different render engine than the Blender Game Engine. It is most similar to Blender Internal. Also, the BGE does not use the compositor.

Comment: Right, but I was just wondering if you can make things glow/emit in the game engine.

Comment: Well you said ". . . but when I switch from cycles render to blender game, it no longer has the same emit effect as before." which is of course expected when changing render engines. Matter of fact no materials should work correctly.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I just wanted to know if you can give it the same effect in the game engine.

Comment: Do you mean applying an emission material, or actually making it glow? I do not know how to do the glow part, but the emission material is easy enough.

Comment: Would adding the emission material give it roughly the same effect? If so, that would be helpful.

Comment: Probably not on its own. Could you post an image of the effect you want to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the object is supposed to move around, you're best off parenting a point lamp to it of the same color.

1. Add lamp and object at the same location
2. Make material for object "shadeless"
3. Make lamp same color (copy/paste hexadecimal values)
4. Parent lamp to object
5. Profit

[image]

if the object *isn't going to be moving* i.e. a stationary lamp or glowy gem, or wall torch or dropped phone the best route to take is to bake all the textures of the objects around it. this should save alot of processor speed since it doesn't have to render *another lamp*.

if you want me to write that part too, I can. but for now look up "cycles texture baking" on youtube. it will make your life much happier.

Comment: since you accepted i assumed it worked for you. :) glad.